# Check if radio button value is, then echo some HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I want to check if the value of the select field is some value and if it is, it needs to echo some text.

I use this code for input box in the form:

```
<li>
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Would you recommend this product to a friend?') ?></strong>
        <?php foreach ( $this->getOptions() as $option ): ?>
            <label class="recommend">
            <input type="radio" name="recommend" id="recommend_field
                <?php echo $option['value'] ?>" class="radio-gender" value="
                <?php echo $option['value'] ?>"
                <?php if ($option['value'] == $value) 
                    echo ' checked="checked"' ?> >
                <?php echo $this->__($option['label']) ?></input>
        </label>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

And I currently echo the entire value of the input box with this line:

```
<div id="reviewwriter">
   <span class="recommendation">
      <?php echo $this->getAnswer() ?>
   </span>
</div>
```

Code is loaded by this php:

```
public function confRecommendItemsArray()
{
    $resArray = array();
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('advancedreviews/recommend_options/recommend_field1')) {
        $resArray[] = array(
            'value' => 1,
            'label' => Mage::getStoreConfig('advancedreviews/recommend_options/recommend_field1')
        );
    }
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('advancedreviews/recommend_options/recommend_field2')) {
        $resArray[] = array(
            'value' => 2,
            'label' => Mage::getStoreConfig('advancedreviews/recommend_options/recommend_field2')
        );
    }
```

And

```
class AW_AdvancedReviews_Block_Recommend_Field extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function canShow()
    {
        return (Mage::helper('advancedreviews')->confShowRecommend()
            && count(Mage::helper('advancedreviews')->confRecommendItemsArray()));
    }

    public function getOptions()
    {
        return Mage::helper('advancedreviews')->confRecommendItemsArray();
    }
}
```

The values of the select field are 
1. Yes 
2. No

I want to check if value is Yes and if so echo 'Value is Yes'.
And if value is No than echo ''.

See also this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wL3xu9d7/1/
But I do not know why it is not working.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: add javascript tag to the list of tags for this question

Comment: where do you want to echo 'Value is Yes' and what is the triggering even (after clicking or onloading) ?

Comment: PHP can't echo things out based on the user choosing a field value in the browser. PHP is server side and is not actively aware of what is going on in the client. You need to use either Javascript or AJAX to have something output to the user when they select something.

Comment: @K.C. I want to echo the 'Value is Yes' in the place where I currently echo the entire <?php echo $this->getAnswer() ?>. So instead it echos the value 'Yes', I want to replace this by 'Value is Yes'. Triggering is after the entire form is placed, so it does not effect the radio buttons directly. I want to echo the value after the form is placed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this solution you want...

```
<li>
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Would you recommend this product to a friend?') ?></strong>
        <?php foreach ( $this->getOptions() as $option ): ?>
        <label class="recommend">
        <input type="radio" name="recommend" id="recommend_field<?php echo $option['value'] ?>" class="radio-gender" value="<?php echo $option['value'] ?>"<?php if ($option['value'] == $value) echo ' checked="checked"' ?>><?php echo $this->__($option['label']) ?></input>
        </label>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>

</li>
```

add hidden field on answer

```
<div id="reviewwriter">
   <span class="recommendation" id="reviewwriteranswer">
      <?php echo $this->getAnswer() ?>
   </span>

</div>

    <script>
$$(".radio-gender").each(function(el) {
            el.observe("click", function(event) { 
                if(el.checked)
                { 


                sub = $('reviewwriteranswer').value;
              sub ==sub =.trim();
                    if(el.value==sub)
                    {
                        $('reviewwriteranswer').update('value is yes');
                    }else {
                        $('reviewwriteranswer').update('value is No');
                    }
                }
            });
        });

</script>
<scrip>
var allElements = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
    var text = allElements[i].innerHTML;
    text=text.trim();

    if (text == 'Yes') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "Value is Yes";
    }
    if (text == 'No') {
        allElements[i].innerHTML = "Value is No";
    }
}
</scrip>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried you code, but it does not seem to work. And I currently echo the value on a other place than in the form where the radio buttons are displayed. I echo the value with this <?php echo $this->getAnswer() ?> on a other place. So I need to check if getAnswer is 'Yes' and then echo the line value is yes.

Comment: Yes indeed, I want to check if the answer is value 'Yes' and if so, it needs to echo that line.

Comment: Div id is 'reviewwriter'

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is still not working. I just echo the entire value of the input with this line <?php echo $this->getAnswer() ?>. But in your new code, its not checking if value is 'Yes'.

Comment: You HTML is different than mine. Is it still working with my HTML?

Comment: No sorry, it is still not working. I do not want to edit the radio button form. I only want to edit the value if it is 'Yes'. So I only need to edit the answer, that if the answer is 'Yes' it should replace html with 'Value is Yes'. Is it possible with innerHTML?

Comment: i treid with innerHTML but it not match the values

Comment: update answer about ur jsfiddle question. put code there and see result

Comment: update the answer too just add id on span the old code will work too